# Displaying Segmented Control with ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following code which displays only the top appBar in Flutter. If I remove the ListView then I see the Segmented Control but if I keep the ListView then I don't see anything as shown below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext build) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Movies')
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              child: 
                Padding(  
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                  children: genreWidgets,
                  onValueChanged: (int val) { },
                )
            ))
          , ListView(children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('First Item'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.map)
            ), 
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Second Item'), 
              leading: Icon(Icons.message)
            )
          ],)
          ])
        ) 
    );

  }
```

Comment: The ListView is not getting displayed. The screenshot in the original questions shows the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a `ListView` inside a `Column`. Instead, you should try `CustomScrollView` with a list of slivers.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Movies')),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                children: genreWidgets,
                onValueChanged: (int val) {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          ListTile(
            title: Text('First Item'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.map),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Second Item'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.message),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Why can't I have a ListView inside a Column? How can a developer know that this is not possible. There are no errors or messages on the debug log.

Comment: I got a lot of errors in my console as soon as I ran your code.

Comment: You cannot have a `ListView` inside a `Column` because your list tries to expand in the main axis, but the main axis is another list so it can expand infinitely.